# Upload Write stream to ftp server with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, ftplib, node-ftp

I've building an application using sockets where user can upload huge files from frontend. I'm saving the file in chunks into temp folder so that i can combine all the file once the upload is done and move to original location. But I want to move the chunk files to ftp server instead of temp folder, I've checked few ftp client libraries where it is accepting the file name, Is there any way to pass bytestream to FTP.

Comment: Are you using websocket or express/koa?

Comment: thats irrelevan jorgen